# wxWidgets screenshot leaves most of image blank when applying to wxstaticbitmap

Tags: c++, screenshot, wxwidgets

When I tried capturing the wxwidgets screenshot, it doesn't showed any error. If I save it, it saves perfectly. But when I try to add it to a static bitmap, it just shows some icons and everything leaves transparent.

```
wxClientDC dcScreen(GetParent());

//Get the size of the screen/DC
wxCoord screenWidth, screenHeight;
dcScreen.GetSize(&screenWidth, &screenHeight);

//Create a Bitmap that will later on hold the screenshot image
//Note that the Bitmap must have a size big enough to hold the screenshot
//-1 means using the current default colour depth
screenshot.Create(screenWidth, screenHeight,-1);

//Create a memory DC that will be used for actually taking the screenshot
wxMemoryDC memDC;
//Tell the memory DC to use our Bitmap
//all drawing action on the memory DC will go to the Bitmap now
memDC.SelectObject(screenshot);
//Blit (in this case copy) the actual screen on the memory DC
//and thus the Bitmap
memDC.Blit( 0, //Copy to this X coordinate
         0, //Copy to this Y coordinate
         screenWidth, //Copy this width
        screenHeight, //Copy this height
        &dcScreen, //From where do we copy?
        0, //What's the X offset in the original DC?
        0  //What's the Y offset in the original DC?
     );
//Select the Bitmap out of the memory DC by selecting a new
//uninitialized Bitmap
memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);

staticbitmap1->SetBitmap(screenshot);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [wxStaticBitmap  docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_static_bitmap.html) you can read:

> Native implementations on some platforms are only meant for display of
>   the small icons in the dialog boxes.
>
> If you want to display larger images portably, you may use generic
>   implementation wxGenericStaticBitmap declared in
>   .

It seems your screenshot is **not small**, and so the OS is messing you. Thus follow the advice and use `wxGenericStaticBitmap`